# Tagging in log messages

Tags: error-logging

I want to tag the log messages in a given request, you can say in a given functional flow, So that while triaging any defect on the application it will be easy to search the messages based on the tag.

Comment: What is the context and the technology you're going to use?
Have you tried some sort of "code-error type" notification? Like [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: In my project Spring along with Log4J is used, to log messages. Its having normal Log4J format. I need to have a tag based on the functional flow, i mean the value of the tag will be dynamic, and will get populated and logged based what is the operation that is tried to perform on the application